# Package is found but contents are not?

Tags: go

I get a strange error while building my go project.

My structure:

```
-$GOPATH
 -src
   -main
     -main.go
   -configuration
     -configuration.go
```

configuration.go:

```
package configuration;

type Config int;

func (c Config) Parse(s string) map[string]string {...}
```

main.go

```
package main;

import"configuration"

func main() {
    var config Config;
    argMap := config.parse(...);    
    return;
}
```

if my working directory is `$GOPATH`, I do:

```
go build configuration - no output, OK
go build main
    imported and not used "configuration"
    undefined: Config
```

So my package is found (`$GOPATH/pkg` contains `configuration.go` with correct content - I can see the `Parse` method) and `main` imports it, but does not recognize its contents?

I recon the problem is that the type `Config` is not exported? Why would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argMap := config.parse(...);`  wouldn't work, since you declared a `Parse()` method.
(as in "exported method `configuration.Parse()`")

```
var config configuration.Config
argMap := config.Parse(...);
```

`Config` is exported, but the methods are case-sensitive (cf. [Exported Identifiers](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `Config` from package `main`, where it is not defined, instead of the one from `configuration` (thats the error "imported and not used"):

```
package main

import "configuration"

func main() {
    var config configuration.Config
    argMap := config.Parse(...)
}
```

The second problem is calling unexported `parse` instead of `Parse` as explained by VonC.